# How to get uploaded file name from the textarea using ckeditor4 in codeigniter4?

Tags: textarea, codeigniter-4, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor4 and I want to get file name and other information in codeigniter4.

Here is my textarea in view file:
`<textarea id="pagecontent" name="pagecontent"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Page Content"></textarea>`

I am using this sentence to get file info.

`$file_info = $this->request->getFile('pagecontent');`

But I am not getting, is it correct?

I am newbie in CI4 so please give the solution here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just to point you in the right direction, take a look at this [CKEditor5 - Simple upload adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa
I am using,
ckeditor4 - textarea (for upload image) - ci4
Just want to get uploaded image name in ci4 manner not  using (_FILE).

Comment: I got the answer,

`$this->request->getFile('upload');`

You will get an object and do your stuff.